# Are there any plans to create printable CVs on careers?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I'd really like careers.stackoverflow.com to be where I keep my most up-to-date version of my CV.  That being said, can we have a way to, say, convert our CV information into a PDF for printing?

Of course, this suggests that we would be sending out CVs to potential employers who have not paid to be a part of the careers site.  But, on the other hand, we *are* paying for this service and I think it would be a nice addition.

Thoughts?

Comment: I see the status-planned tag, which I presume to be added by Jeff.  Is there an update on when we might see this feature request?

Comment: Print stylesheet still looks like ass, please implement something. DO MOAR NOW!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I like this idea. This could be very useful. I sure hate having so many different copies of mine.

Comment: +1 Absolutely.  Trying to manage three different copies when you can't remember which is the master is a headache I'd like to alleviate if possible.

Comment: I would just be happy with a link to my standard resume.  Because the formatting of the resume really matters, and easily differentiates candidates.  Also they are going to ask for a Word copy of your resume regardless to feed in to their HR system, so why not help them out with the process.  This stackoverflow careers site seems very focused at the way startups CV's function, or maybe a west coast mentality towards employement, not multi-billion dollar enterprises that are readily found on the east cost.

Answer (score 5):

How about an API -- then you can extract the vitals from your CV, slice, dice and present it however you want. Show off your `( HTML | PS | PDF | SVG | LaTeX | ... )` foo at the same time.

If the API can ping a URL, you can put together a one-click build for all the versions of your Resume.

Answer (score 3):

I'm bumping this question for two reasons:

1. I'd really like to get see this done soon. I'm currently transitioning to careers.stackoverflow.com as my only available resume, and I need the ability to send a paper (or digital paper (heh!)) copy when necessary. I'm willing to help out on this, if you just need somebody to do teh codez.
2. Feature request! The CV doesn't collect (and therefore can't print) personal contact information (phone, address, email, that sort of thing), something that has to be on any printed CV. So I'd like to see careers accept that information and add it to the exported print, but without displaying it on the online CV.

Answer (score -2):

I don't really want the StackOverflow version in a PDF format.  I want a link to my own.  In a previous post that was closed as a duplicate for this one (which it wasn't now that I read this post), I stated:

> I would like to request that the
>   careers.stackoverflow site allow for a
>   link to an outside PDF/Word document
>   link that employers can download.
>
> I think what the stackoverflow team
>   has done is great, but many HR
>   departments like to pass around
>   official looking resumes. Not only
>   that but a well prepared and good
>   looking resume is the first indication
>   you can give to an employer that you
>   are detailed oriented.

So just a simple link where I can point people that are interested in my resume to a professional looking CV that is well formatted and shows the level of professionalism that I will bring to the job.

Comment: I daresay this is what the whole concept is CSO is trying to get away from - Asking the questions in the CV form that they believe to be the most important and most relevant to the types of employees that employers are looking for.

Comment: No matter how good CSO is going to be for finding good qualified candidates, it isn't going to change the fact of the modern HR department.  A majority of the larger ones require a word copy of the resume on file.

Comment: So link to your word or pdf or rtf or whatever other obscure format at the bottom in the "other links" section.