# Careers: CVs ugly when saved or printed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, cv

In my company, we copy the CV into a meeting request for the interviewer to read. I can't find a "save as PDF" or "print" option, so I save the CV as a web page and attach that to the meeting request, but it looks pretty ugly when the interviewer looks at it (I assume the CSS is lost for one thing). A PDF export option that looks nice would be very helpful.

I use both IE8 and Firefox 3 and neither looks very nice when saved.

Comment: PDF export is already planned according to Jeff Atwood: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24976/are-there-any-plans-to-create-printable-cvs-on-careers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Careers now has a print style defined<sup>1</sup>.

The way browsers munged style sheets for printing isn't standardized, so the style basically removes all the color.  It also removes the "website" bits, like navigation links and logos.

<sub><sup>1</sup>More strictly, on the public and employer pages for CVs.</sub>

Comment: Looks great when I print from Opera now. Strangely, it still seems to have colours. Also when I print from the [saved] tab, the box with the remove button is still there, which looks a little odd. Otherwise it works fine. (It crashes when I print from Firefox, but I think that must be something odd in my setup, not the page.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a huge issue for many companies that still must pass paper and PDF copies around.  A printable CSS should be a requirement, especially since one can't pass a URL that shows the employer's view without signing in.  Given the number of people involved in hiring in even medium sized companies, and how many of them have to sign off on a document with the prospect information attached before even requesting an interview, I'm surprised this hasn't already been requested.

Comment: You can't? http://careers.stackoverflow.com/adamdavis

Comment: @voy - The employer view and the public view can be different, and that's not something the employer can control for.  In fact you can list your CV for employers, and have it publicly unavailable.  So yes, this is still a problem requiring a solution.

Answer (score 2):

What browser? That is the one responsible of translating the layout for printing.

A `media="print"` CSS would be welcomed anyway (I see none), and would require less work than a PDF export.

Comment: You could always use a print-to-PDF driver, to get the PDF.

Comment: @Brad, the PDF export was proposed merely because some browsers have very poor printing capabilities and it print differently from browser to browser, but I've found that if you go for a simple layout, you have little to worry about in that front.