# How do I print my CV

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, cv, printing

I actually have an interview, thanks to careers.stackoverflow.com!!  Woohoo!  The employer just asked me for a copy of my résumé, which is woefully out of date.  I'd like to both send them a PDF copy of my CV (I have a PDF print driver), and use that same PDF as a comparison tool for editing my old résumé.  I found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40403/careers-cvs-ugly-when-saved-or-printed), but when I File-->Print in FireFox, I get a blank page.

Comment: Just write out "I am Batman" on a piece of construction paper in brown crayon. That hasn't failed me yet.

Comment: @NIfE - Please define "fail" with respect to your comment.  I suspect you and I have very, very different perspectives on failure.

Comment: @Pollyanna: Technically, it hasn't failed for me either. I have a perfect 0/0 success rate.

Comment: @mmyers assuming you define perfect as 100%, 0/0 isn't a perfect success rate, it is a NaN% success rate.

Comment: @Kip: How can you possibly get more perfect than NaN?

Comment: @mmyers inf% would be the best

Comment: @AJ - this is now fixed, you should be able to print the employer view tab as well as the public view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of FireFox are you running?  Any potentially troublesome extensions?  Which page exactly?  Obviously it's working for me, but I'd like to investigate anyway.

For the immediate future I suggest printing using IE or Chrome (or Safari, etc.).

Comment: I'm attempting to print from the Employer View.  I'm using FireFox 3.6.2.  I will try using the only other browser I'm allowed at work (IE6, blech) and let you know.

Comment: Same thing in IE6.  I must be printing from the wrong page...?

Comment: @AJ - which page are you trying to print?

Comment: @Kevin Montrose - attempting to print from the Employer View tab.  Am I missing something completely obvious, like the "Print View" tab?

Comment: @AJ - no, I'm just trying to reproduce the problem, which I now have actually.  A quick fix would be to publish your CV (http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/publish/), and print that page.  You can un-publish it afterwards.

Comment: @Kevin - that works!  I already had my CV published, so it was just a matter of going to the public view URL.  It would be nice if we could print from the employer view or otherwise, though.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Prints up nice and purty for me on IE8.